# Rename files without extension with AutoHotkey

Tags: file-io, rename, autohotkey, batch-rename

I am trying to add .pdf to the filename of files without extension in a folder.

It is possible to rename for example txt files to pdf using the following command:

```
FileMove, %SourceFolder%\*.txt, %SourceFolder%\*.pdf
```

Also, I can add .pdf to all files by:

```
FileMove, %SourceFolder%\*, %SourceFolder%\*.pdf
```

But I only want to target only the files **without extension**. How to do this?

Comment: I don't think it's possible using a single file pattern. Why don't you just `Loop` over each file and check its extension?

Comment: @MCL The [AutoHotkey "Loop" docs](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/LoopFile.htm) show how to target a particular extension with A_LoopFileExt. However, it does not say how to select files without extension.

Comment: You don't have to select only those files without an extension using a file pattern. In fact, I believe you actually can't with AHK. You `Loop` over **every** file (no matter if it has an extension). Then, for each file, you check if it has an extension and move/rename it if it doesn't. `FileMove` also accepts single files!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Example

As suggested by [kasper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1469111/kasper) and [MCL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1282023/mcl)

```
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%

Loop, files\*
{
    if !StrLen(A_LoopFileExt) ; if no file extension
    {
        FileMove,%A_LoopFileFullPath%,%A_LoopFileFullPath%.pdf ;rename file
    }
}
```

see [[Loop, FilePattern]](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/LoopFile.htm)
see [[FileMove]](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/FileMove.htm)

Comment: You could actually just use the pattern `files\*`. Although `*.*` works as well (as of now), it actually should not, since it requires a dot in the file name.

Answer (score 0):

@kasper, You can use windows command prompt to rename the file as well as change the extension.
Just navigate to the file directory and use command

```
ren abc.txt abc.pdf
```

Here abc.txt is old file and abc.pdf is pdf of abc.txt.

Comment: OP wants to rename files *without* an extension, and with Autohotkey at that.

Comment: This indeed does not solve my problem at all: I only want to select files without extension.